# Can i use the Git on my cpanel

Tags: git

I am new to the web world and recently start learning about the GIT, The technique of Git is now on my head, But i don't know where and how to use this.

I know about the **GitHub** and **Bit Bucket** from where we can use Git to fetching the data and updating.

> What i want to know is, **Can i use the Git for my cpanel**?? My Hosting
>   is on site5.

May be this very easy and boring question to someone of you, but for me its now mandatory things. I want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how to relate this with [cpanel](/questions/tagged/cpanel), but you need a so-called *Git Server*. These are implemented in various languages, so some might fit for the hosting you're already using, some not.

Here is a list of Git server implementations that come to my mind:

- [built-in in the Git packages](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) itself (optionally together with [gitweb](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb)) (C/C++ + Perl IIRC)
- [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) (Ruby(
- [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com) (Java)
- [GoGS](https://github.com/gogits/gogs) (Go)